# How to configure Netbeans to format class field declarations (or even local variables) to line up?

Tags: java, netbeans, formatting, settings, netbeans-7

I can't find an option in Netbeans (7) to align variables. For example, I want to change this:

```
private int hello = 1;
private static int hello2 = 1;
public static String hello3 = "yo";
private final static int HELLO3 = 1;
private String stringy = "testing hello";
private char c = 'a';
```

into this (or something similar):

```
private                 int       hello      = 1;
private static          int       hello2     = 1;
private final static    int       HELLO3     = 1;
private                 char      c          = 'a';
private                 String    stringy    = "testing hello";
public static           String    hello3     = "yo";
```

when I press Format (`alt+shift+f`).

Also, I'd like it to be applicable to local variables, so that this:

```
private void Test()
{
    int x = 2;
    String z = "test";
    int[] y = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

would change into this:

```
private void Test()
{
    int       x    = 2;
    int[]     y    = {1, 2, 3};
    String    z    = "test";
}
```

I've looked in `Tools->Options->Editor->Language "Java"->Category "Alignment"`, however, I found nothing that affects this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Jindent plugin](http://www.jindent.com/downloads/item/jindent-ide-plugins/jindent-netbeans-plugin) for Netbeans. But there is a caveat: it is a limited evaluation version. You have to pay for the full version.